# Omnichannel queue-based and normal queue routing

Tags: omnichannel

I want to use queue based routing in omnichannel but, there is also the standard queue assignement in salesforce, that most people have used until now.

Can we do both at the same time ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: As far as I know a user cannot be assigned to both omnichannel and other configuration at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Only records that use "Channels" which are configured for routing through omni-channel will go to the queues configured to receive them through omni-channel. Any other records that are set up using "normal" assignment and routing rules will still be routed to the queues they're currently configured to use. When you split them like this, you lose the real benefits of omni-channel. But, when you're in the transition to omni-channel, yes, it can be done this way, just don't mix queues with feeds of records coming from omni-channel and other routing configurations.